# faster strlen?

Tags: c, algorithm, string

Typical `strlen()` traverse from first character till it finds `\0`.
This requires you to traverse each and every character.
In algorithm sense, its O(N).

Is there any faster way to do this where input is vaguely defined. 
Like: length would be less than 50, or length would be around 200 characters.

I thought of lookup blocks and all but didn't get any optimization.

Comment: @Geo [Cute](https://xkcd.com/221/), but that doesn't implement `strlen` for the vast majority of inputs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually, [glibc's implementation](http://tsunanet.net/~tsuna/strlen.c.html) of `strlen` is an interesting example of the vectorization approach. It is peculiar in that it doesn't use vector instructions, but finds a way to use only ordinary instructions on 32 or 64 bits words from the buffer.

Comment: On the other hand, at least on x86/x86_64 and gcc, you'll just get the compiler's builtin anyway.

Comment: Yes, you have to give it another name if you want to make sure the version used is yours. If you are going to do this, you might as well somehow ensure that all strings your version will be passed are word-aligned (if possible) and remove the initial char-by-char loop completely.

Comment: Now there is SSE2 version of strlen : https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S;hb=HEAD

Comment: @Simon And how can I compile this with Visual C++ ?

Answer (score 29):

Sure.  Keep track of the length while you're writing to the string.

Comment: +1: Hooray Fortran (and don't allow to change it in any way after the declaration)

Comment: i did large improvements on strcat using this technique

Comment: Bob, most of the time, its possible to maintain explicit length when we are writing string. 



Sometimes, its not possible :( For exa: reading stream from file or network. I might have got 500 characters but only first 200 character makes valid string and remaining 300 are not useful

Comment: That... doesn't sound right to me.  Most situations involving file/network IO give you back the number of bytes read.

Comment: Yes, they do give numbers of byte read. What if I am not interested in all of them but need just first valid string?

Comment: YES.

Also, please understand that not all programs behave the way you want. You might get this string from other process/machine where you don't have much of control.

In general, my intention was to improve strlen prototype.

Comment: If that's what you're trying to do, then no, it's not possible to do better than O(n).  `strlen` is what you want.

Comment: +0: Hooray COBOL! (+0 because I'm not registered :( )

Answer (score 11):

Obviously, if your string has a known minimum length, you can begin your search at that position.

Beyond that, there's not really anything you can do; if you try to do something clever and find a `\0` byte, you still need to check every byte between the start of the string and that point to make sure there was no earlier `\0`.

That's not to say that `strlen` can't be optimized.  It can be pipelined, and it can be made to process word-size or vector chunks with each comparison.  On most architectures, some combination of these and other approaches will yield a substantial constant-factor speedup over a naive byte-comparison loop.  Of course, on most mature platforms, the system `strlen` is already implemented using these techniques.

Answer (score 5):

Jack,

`strlen` works by looking for the ending '\0', here's an implementation taken from OpenBSD:

```
size_t
strlen(const char *str)
{
        const char *s;

        for (s = str; *s; ++s)
                ;
        return (s - str);
}
```

Now, consider that you know the length is about 200 characters, as you said. Say you start at 200 and loop up and down for a '\0'. You've found one at 204, what does it mean? That the string is 204 chars long? NO! It could end before that with another '\0' and all you did was look out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
As I said, length is vaguely predicted and may not end after character 200.
Also, if we start reading after 200th character, we might be reading invalid string (if string has ended around 100 character...)

Comment: Link also says same: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/string/strlen.c?annotate=1.7

Answer (score 4):

Get a Core i7 processor.

Core i7 comes with the SSE 4.2 instruction set. Intel added four additional vector instructions to speed up strlen and related search tasks.

Here are some interesting thoughts about the new instructions:

http://smallcode.weblogs.us/oldblog/2007/11/

Comment: Thanks for answer. As George Verghese says, hardware boost always helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Here I attached the asm code from glibc 2.29. I removed the snippet for ARM cpus. I tested it, it is really fast, beyond my expectation. It merely do alignment then 4 bytes comparison.

```
ENTRY(strlen)
bic     r1, r0, $3              @ addr of word containing first byte
ldr     r2, [r1], $4            @ get the first word
ands    r3, r0, $3              @ how many bytes are duff?
rsb     r0, r3, $0              @ get - that number into counter.
beq     Laligned                @ skip into main check routine if no more
orr     r2, r2, $0x000000ff     @ set this byte to non-zero
subs    r3, r3, $1              @ any more to do?
orrgt   r2, r2, $0x0000ff00     @ if so, set this byte
subs    r3, r3, $1              @ more?
orrgt   r2, r2, $0x00ff0000     @ then set.
Laligned:               @ here, we have a word in r2.  Does it
tst     r2, $0x000000ff         @ contain any zeroes?
tstne   r2, $0x0000ff00         @
tstne   r2, $0x00ff0000         @
tstne   r2, $0xff000000         @
addne   r0, r0, $4              @ if not, the string is 4 bytes longer
ldrne   r2, [r1], $4            @ and we continue to the next word
bne     Laligned                @
Llastword:              @ drop through to here once we find a
tst     r2, $0x000000ff         @ word that has a zero byte in it
addne   r0, r0, $1              @
tstne   r2, $0x0000ff00         @ and add up to 3 bytes on to it
addne   r0, r0, $1              @
tstne   r2, $0x00ff0000         @ (if first three all non-zero, 4th
addne   r0, r0, $1              @  must be zero)
DO_RET(lr)
```

END(strlen)

Comment: This is useless. All the `strlen`s that use 4 or 8 bytes checks are `ACCESS VIOLATION` waiting to happen at any moment. This assumes that you can safely read past the end of the string, but it never can be assumed.

Comment: I am curious which systems have byte level access violation boundaries? Most systems do access violation at the page boundary and most pages are at least 4k in size. The writers of glibc aren't going to drop a strlen that is going to run past the end of page.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: no.

The longer answer: do you really think that if there were a faster way to check string length for barebones C strings, something as commonly used as the C string library wouldn't have already incorporated it?

Without some kind of additional knowledge about a string, you have to check each character. If you're willing to maintain that additional information, you could create a `struct` that stores the length as a field in the struct (in addition to the actual character array/pointer for the string), in which case you could then make the length lookup constant time, but would have to update that field each time you modified the string.

Comment: Then we'd have Pascal strings all over again. :)

Comment: But we'd probably have fewer buffer overflows (if they were either built-in to the language or used consistently) - which would be a Good Thing!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use vectorization. Not sure if compiler will be able perform it, but I did it manually (using intrinsics). But it could help you only for long strings.

Use stl strings, it's more safe and std::string class contains its length.

Comment: How would vectorization help?  Even if the buffer was, say, 4 KB, there's no guarantee about the contents of the string after the first null, so if the vectorization started 4 operations (threads?) on the 1 KB boundaries, there's no telling what the three starting from a non-zero offset would see.  I suppose the result would have to be the minimum of the 4 returned values - where the non-zero offset threads would have to add their starting position to the returned length.

Comment: I think Elalfer is proposing to assign each consecutive byte to a vector to be checked as a whole, and then scrolling the string scan of the length of the vector. That would definitely work, assuming you have a vector-based architecture.

Comment: @Jonathan Vectorization is not using threads! Vectorization means using the SIMD programming model to check consecutive bytes for zero simultaneously. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD It helps that vector alignment always make them fit in a single page. This implementation typically overflows the buffer but that is not caught by the MMU. We find these benign buffer overflows in the analyzer I work on. See also http://tsunanet.net/~tsuna/strlen.c.html for an impressive C implementation without special vector instructions.

Comment: @Jonathan: There is for example the "pcmpeqb" instructions, which compares 16 bytes at once. Additionally SSE 4.2 contains specific vector extensions for strings, like "pcmpistri". This has nothing to to with threading.

Comment: It would greatly depend on your average string size. If your average string size is large. You will definitely benefit from SIMD. If your average string size is small you will not benefit from it. As with everything strive for results based on measurement (aka science) and not hype (aka dogma)

Answer (score 0):

If you control the allocation of the string, you could make sure there is not just one terminating `\0` byte, but several in a row depending on the maximum size of vector instructions for your platform. Then you could write the same O(n) algorithm using X bytes at a time comparing for 0, making `strlen` amortized O(n/X). Note that the amount of extra `\0` bytes would not be equal to the amount of bytes on which your vector instructions operate (X), but rather 2*X - 1 since an aligned region should be filled with zeroes.

You would need to iterate over a couple of bytes normally in the beginning though, until you reach an address that is aligned to a boundary of X bytes.

The use case for this is kind of non-existent though: the amount of extra bytes you need to allocate would easily be more than simply storing a simple 4 or 8 byte integer containing the size directly. Even if it is  important to you for some reason that this string can be passed solely as a pointer, without passing its size as well I think storing the size as the first Y bytes during allocation might be the fastest. But this is already far from the `strlen` optimization you're asking about.

Clarification:

```
the_size | the string ...
         ^
 the pointer to the string
```

The glibc implementation is way cooler.

Comment: Yes, but rounding up to the next 8 byte boundary costs no more than having the 8-byte counter, and occasionally saves a byte. It always saves a word if the strings are being allocated by an aligned allocator anyway. So not a totally bad idea.