# How to get the length of all strings in an object in C

Tags: c, string, typedef

I have a structure which includes 7 different strings in it. I need to find the total length of those strings in the object. Here is my type:

```
typedef struct
{
    char activity   [250]; 
    char adv_MAC    [250];   
    char PTx        [250]; 
    char refRSSI    [250]; 
    char RSSI       [250]; 
    char tick       [250];  
    char locatorID  [250];  
} report_data_t;   /**< BLE temporary report data struct */
```

I'm not looking for the size of the object. I'm lokking for the length of each string in the object. I already tried to use

```
strlen(o1.activity);
```

But my purpose is to achieve this in the **shortest** way.

Comment: Using `strlen` to get the length of a null-terminated string *is* the "shortest" way to get its length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [faster strlen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774791/faster-strlen)

Comment: I coulnd't find an answer for my problem. Could you please tell me which entry should I look? I'm looking for the total length of strings in an object. @EliahuAaron

Comment: @ÇağlayanDÖKME: There isn't a simple faster way than `strlen` as you can see from the answers here:  [faster strlen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774791/faster-strlen)

Comment: @ÇağlayanDÖKME C is not an object-oriented language...

Comment: You are aware that the size of an instance of `report_data_t` is completed independent from the length of the "string"s it holds? It is of constant size, namely `sizeof (report_data_t)`, which is guaranteed to be greater or equal to the sum of the length of all the strings held by its elements.

Comment: *But my purpose is to achieve this in the **shortest** way.* So you've profiled your application and you know that `strlen()` is a huge performance bottleneck?  If the answer to that isn't "Yes" - meaning you have both actually profiled the performance of your application **and** found that `strlen()` is a performance bottleneck, you're wasting your time engaging in premature optimization.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper way would be to simply enumerate the memmbers:

```
size_t sz = 0;
sz+=strlen(d->activity);
sz+=strlen(d->adv_MAC);
sz+=strlen(d->PTx);
sz+=strlen(d->refRSSI);
sz+=strlen(d->RSSI);
sz+=strlen(d->tick);
sz+=strlen(d->locatorID);
```

It's pretty easy to type with a smart editor.

In your case, you could also simply do:

```
size_t sz = 0; for(int i=0;i<7;i++) sz+=strlen(&d->activity[250*i]);
```

while asserting that there's no padding (the standard doesn't guarantee it but for
a struct consisting of only chars it should be true):

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(report_data_t)==7*250,"");
```

Comment: Are you sure this `for(int i=0;i<7;i++ ... activity[250*i]);` isn't invoking UB, even without  padding?

Comment: @alk `((char*)&d)+250*i` would be somewhat less controversial I guess. `&d->activity[250*i]` is the same as `d->activity+250*i`. `d->activity` decays to a `char*`.  `d->activity+250*i` for i in 0...6 is within the range of the struct object and the bytes of any object may be accessed through a char* pointer without violating strict aliasing rules. So, I don't think it is UB but I welcome any proof that I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As usual it's not clear what "short" means: are you after compact code, or high performance?

Since it's a lot of structure to exploit, I might go for a data-driven approach:

```
size_t report_strlen(const report_data_t *r)
{
  static const size_t strs[] = {
    offsetof(report_data_t, activity), offsetof(report_data_t, adv_MAC),
    offsetof(report_data_t, PTx),      offsetof(report_data_t, refRSSI),
    offsetof(report_data_t, RSSI),     offsetof(report_data_t, tick),
    offsetof(report_data_t, locatorID),
  };
  size_t len = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof strs / siezof *strs; ++i)
  {
    len += strlen((const char *) r + strs[i]);
  }
  return len;
}
```

On second thought, it's probably not worth it and I'd just stack in all the explicit calls to `strlen()`, that's more approachable and 7 is not quite many enough to warrant the above.